# keyboard switching from portrait to landscape the view remains shifted up after closing of keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard

The keyboard is brought in the view in portrait mode and then the rotated to landscape mode.
The keyboard is closed programmatically by

`InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);`

after closing the keyboard is shifting down the view that was shifted in portrait mode.

This works fine if the keyboard in closed in portrait mode. or opened in landscape mode and closed in the same mode.

I am testing on vanilla android and running on Motorola phones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change activity configuration in manifest as follows:
`android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
 android:screenOrientation="portrait"
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`